# Downloading Facebook Videos from the Blob Infrastructure via Python

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, blob-video-download

I've tried in various way to download a regular mp4 file from a facebook/video page. As far as I understand it's saved inside a blob infrastrucure which, is based in few javascripts which are generate out of the blob infrastructure a playable video.
Now is my question how I would be able to get the needed Javascripts, and how I would be able to execute them to generate the video.

Comment: I've already tested it with the "network trick" to get a pagelink with the whole mp4 file, but as far as I have seen, there are just segments of the video

Comment: maybe I'm totally wrong with my way of thinking about it. I would be happy to get any other working way.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to get the video directly from the cache of the ram?

Comment: Facebook only allows you to use their API and will give you a URL to download

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have another problem. I have a public facebook video (and I know that it is set on public), but I get that error which I can't pass:
"(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details."

Comment: And I can't find anything working on the pages facebook shows me